# Compatibility of DNN Package(Module) with older version

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I am going to start on DNN 7 with Visual Studio 2015(DNN Module). As it will be something big for me, I want to make sure about compatibility with all older version. I just afraid if I develop full product and if it will not support to some version, I will need to rework.

I want to create a module which should be used in any DNN based website and it should not have any compatibility issue (i.e DLLs, version) while user adding the module to webpage.

Resource that I am using to create:

> ```
> 1- Visual Studio 2015
> 2- DotnetNuke 7 C# Compiled Module
> 3- Some DLLs like for JSON parshing, CSS, JS etc
> ```

[image]
Will it support for older version website etc? Can anybody suggest your thought above my confusion?

Answer (score 1):

That template will work, without any changes, for pretty much any version of DNN 7 and DNN 8.

They say DNN7 specifically because of the dependency and file references in the various projects in my templates, but you are definitely not confined to using DNN 7.

If you want to use it for older versions of DNN, you can use that as well, You will need to modify the .DNN File to change the "dependency" version, to a lower version. You may also need to remove the DLL references to dotnetnuke.dll and any other dotnetnuke.*.dll files, and re-add them to the version you want to use.

Edit: (More opinion) I wouldn't bother trying to support older versions of DNN, people really need to have upgraded by now, if they haven't, they are security nightmares waiting to happen.